# show image and find $\angle{BAE}$

Tags: geometry

[image: show image and find $\angle{BAE}]

show image and find $\angle{BAE}$

thanks

Comment: you've already asked 4 questions in a very short time, and you show no self effort at all in spite of having been told to before. This is not serious.

Comment: I thank you for those remarks and apologize to all (because, beginning in the English language)
I found the site sobering and effective and you look for different solutions to tack questions
I will try to be an active member
Please accept my apologies
Thank you for all

Answer (score 1):

Draw $AC$. Since the trapezoid is isosceles, its diagonals have the same length. This means that $|AC|=|BD|$. Since $|BD|=|AE|$ it follows that $|AC|=|AE|$. This means that the triangle $ACE$ is isosceles and the angle $A\hat{C}E=70^o$. It follows therefore that $C\hat{A}E=180^o-70^o-70^o=40^o$. Let $F$ be the point of intersection of the two diagonals. Because the trapezoid is isosceles, the diagonals form isosceles triangles with the bases. In particular, the triangle $AFB$ is isosceles with $|AF|=|FB|$. You have that $F\hat{A}B=40^o+x=F\hat{B}A$. On the other hand you have that $C\hat{F}A= F\hat{A}B+F\hat{B}A=x+40^o+x+15^o$. This gives $70^o=2x+55^o$. Therefore $x=7.5^o$.